# how to set jqplot gradient background

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to set background attribute to gradient color in jqplot? For example

```
$.jqplot(divId, data, {

grid: {
background: "-webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(73,155,234,1)),        color-stop(40%, rgba(73,155,234,1)), color-stop(57%, rgba(32,124,229,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(32,124,229,1)))",
```

},
}